# $_SESSION['username']/hidden value

Tags: php, forms, session, printing

```
<?php
session start();
?>

<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>, 
Please submit this form to book a project room in the Business School.
```

I've been trying to print out the `$_SESSION['username']` on my form. But nothing gets printed. I've passed the `session start();` on all necessary files but it still doesn't work. Please do advise.

I've tried using hidden value also, but it doesn't work. :/

Comment: Did you set `$_SESSION['username']` to anything?

Comment: Is `$_SESSION['username']` set?

Comment: Damn you @Rocket, beat me to it...

Comment: @Rocket & @Kristoffer we set $_SESSION['username'] to our 'username' at login page.

Answer (score 6):

Use `session_start();` instead of `session start();`.

Add `var_dump($_SESSION);` after the session_start() to your script, for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `echo isset( $_SESSION['username'] );`
OR my favourite: `print_r( $_SESSION );` and see everything in the session

Comment: `print_r()` by default already prints out its output, so the echo is not needed. You can capture print_r's output by setting its second optional parameter to TRUE, in which case it would return its output, which you could then echo.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem.
The problem exist when you create a variable like

```
$username
```

Maybe your $username is empty.
I don't know why this is happening.

$username and $_SESSION['username'] are supposed to be not equal or interchangeably.

See the examples below

```
$_SESSION['token'] will change and be equal to $token if you have $token variable
```

I tried to copy the same code I have to the other hosting and that works fine.
So I conclude that the issue belongs to your hosting.